# How to add columns using a dictionary in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to add a column using the dictionary keys into the data frame
This is the current code I try but it didn't return the boroughs instead it returns 'Other' for all

```py
boroughs = {'Manhattan':[1, 2, 3], 
            'Bronx':[4, 5, 6], 
            'Brooklyn':[7, 8, 9],
            'Staten Island': 10}

def test(x):
  for key, value in boroughs.items():
    if int(x) in value or int(x) == value:
      return key
    else:
      return 'Other'
      
df['Boroughs'] = df.precinct.apply(test)
```

After I run the code, this is the current Boroughs

```
precinct   Boroughs
1.0        'Other'
5.0        'Other'
9.0        'Other'
10.0       'Other'
```

This is the expected results

```
precinct   Boroughs
1.0        'Manhattan'
5.0        'Bronx'
9.0        'Brooklyn'
10.0       'Staten Island'
```

I want to know where did I got it wrong thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dict is backwards.  Try this:

```
boroughs = {
    'Manhattan': [1, 2, 3], 
    'Bronx': [4, 5, 6], 
    'Brooklyn': [7, 8, 9],
    'Staten Island': [10],
}

d = {}
for k, v in boroughs.items():
    for num in v:
        d[num] = k

df["Boroughs"] = df.precinct.astype(int).map(d)
```

output:

```
   precinct       Boroughs
0       1.0      Manhattan
1       5.0          Bronx
2       9.0       Brooklyn
3      10.0  Staten Island
```

Side note: dicts aren't guaranteed to be invertible.  here I assume each precinct is associated with a unique Borough.

Comment: Thank you!! This solved my problem! I didn't know map much, I probably going to check them later, two-loop seems logical for me, but I might still be confused by how my original code is wrong.

Comment: Dicts are useful when you know keys and want values - in your case, you know the precinct and want the borough.  All I did was invert the provided dict.  As for `map`: it just replaces keys with values in a dataframe.